# Why is this question downvoted so much?

Tags: discussion

[What are the edges of typical (or specific) paid databases like oracle of mysql compared to the free oness?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20134/why-would-anyone-uses-paid-database-engine-like-microsoft-or-oracle)

I understand that there are many good reason to use paid database engine, such as greater reliability.

However, that's exactly what the question ask. Also, the idea that mysql innodb is not reliable is not something most people are aware of.

Anyway, is the question prohibited due to the answer being too obvious? Off topic, or what?

If you pay because you got things in return like support, stability, predictability, maintenance, built-in security and other out-of-the-box features, why not turn them into an answer? Why downvote the question?

For example, a person can explain what features oracle has that innodb doesn't.

Comment: I'm not sure why it got so many downvotes - it's certainly an interesting question. The way it is phrased makes it sould like you had already made up your mind though? If you can edit it into a 'real', 'constructive' question it is possible it could be re-opened

Comment: I suspect it's because the question sounds like you already have an opinion and are challenging anyone to contradict it.  It comes across not as a real question but as an assertion, "Paid RDBMS are terrible and you don't need them, right?"

Comment: You can also see what features Oracle has that InnoDB doesn't by going and reading the documentation, feature pages, data sheets, etc. This isn't research you need a collective web site to do for you.

Comment: I haven't made up my mind. I am seriously considering new stuffs. Every other start up use free like mongodb and stuffs.

Comment: I think a question should be judged by what's actually asked rather than (FALSE) speculation on whether I have made up my mind or not. Even if I have (I haven't, I am really curious, and I am not a database expert), so what?

Comment: I used to learn math and I often go the extra mile of making sure of things. I guess that's where the impression comes from. There is no way I have made up my mind. The idea that paid database is more secure is not even obvious to me. Also my claim that facebook quora, etc. are the "biggest" is very legitimate. There could be other things that are even bigger but they're not famous. Even then, facebook should be one of the biggest.

Comment: I changed the title of the questions. The answers people telling is exactly what I want to ask.

Comment: Facebook using MySQL is not a valid comparison for you to say "see, they use the free version" because they don't. Their version is a fork, highly tailored to their needs, recompiled by people who seriously know MySQL and who made it work specifically for the needs of Facebook. You can't judge the fact that they used Apache2 for a long time as their server either, because a lot of their code is written directly in C now, and compiled from PHP to C. They have a process unlike any you would recognize, except that the devs do write code you would recognize.

Comment: Wow. Thanks I learn something new.

Comment: The problem with the question is that somehow it generates intense amount of hatred. Something I find very surprising.

Answer (score 5):

> For example, a person can explain what features oracle has that innodb doesn't.

So then you already have an answer in mind? How interesting. So why did you ask an argumentative question, instead of fashioning one that should be objective and direct?

Comment: What mind? No I have not made up my mind. I am thinking of moving to mysql all other start ups recommend a few free alternatives like mongodb. I am seriously considering paid version....

Comment: Change the title of the question to something I believe logically equivalent but perhaps this get the nuance difference.

Comment: Do you understand the fundamental differences between NoSQL DB and RDBMS DB? Do you know how Mongo is different from MySQL? Do you know why people recommend those choices?

Comment: I am a noob about database stack exchange. I know little. That's why I ask around.

Comment: That's why this site is for experts with specific problems, or for those who need the benefits of an expert to answer specific questions. You're apparently, from your comments, more in need of a crash/fresher course so you know what your options are. That's unfortunately outside the scope of this site, directly, however, I can write a blog post on these differences tomorrow. Ping me (here) if that's something you would like to see.

Comment: never mind. Speaking of experts, it looks like people cannot answer difficult questions either here. I did ask some specific questions with no answers. Even if the question seems "easy", they can just answer it rather than making false speculations.

Comment: You, sir, are not being a constructive member of the community. You're welcome to leave and not come back, or you're welcome to learn that we can't teach an entire semester or more of information in one question. If you want expertise that requires a conversation, then have a conversation with an expert. If you want an answer to a question, properly formed, then ask a question, properly formed. Don't accuse of us of being unable to answer the question or of not having the expertise. You have given every inclination for us to believe that you need to HIRE someone, not get help.

Comment: At this point I may be being rude, but at this point you have not helped us help you, you have been insulting, and you have expected a lot of information to be made concise that can not be made concise. There's a reason some of us spend years studying this field, and it's because it's highly complex. You were judgemental of paid products without understanding what the benefits were, and you focused all of your research on a few publicly known companies who experience regular downtime and glitches.

Comment: You didn't ask what database system Ford uses, or SAP, or the Royal Bank of Scotland, or CitiGroup, or Visa. You looked at twitter and facebook and assumed those were the best group of people to consider as database consumers. Then you posited opinionated crap and reasoned that we obviously must not be able to answer questions. At this point, I'll be just as happy to see you leave as to see you a reformed asker. Your call.

Comment: Ford, SAP, Royal bank of scotland is not famous database users. Not among common people and not among startup businesses. Look, I am wrong not to include them, but I have no malicious intent. If I offend anyone I am sorry. I'll move on.

Comment: I am not that noob about databases. I did use it on my startup. It's just that it's not optimized properly.

Comment: You don't offend us, but you speak with a very narrow mindset. The developer can't afford to have a narrow mindset. The developer must be open to every solution that may be valid.